# How to Inspect Validations that exist on ActiveRecord::Base Objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I want to create a helper method to automatically output text_fields with a :maxlength attribute. I want this maxlegth to be set based on the :max specified in the field attributes validates_length validation, so as to remain DRY.

My question is: Is there a good way to inspect the validations that are present on an objects attribute, and then extract the maximum length from that validation.

I also plan on extracting other things like the regex from validates_format so I can set an attribute on the text_field, which can then be used by js to run client side validations.

Thanks.

Bonus points: Why doesn't Rails Automatically add the maxlength to text fields for us?

Comment: Here's another idea. You can make a rake task that scans all the code for your Rails models looking for validations.  Then you could parse all of the validations and convert them into javascript. This seems like a lot of work, though.

Comment: Thanks monocle, I had thought of this, but it seems so hacky! You are right, it does sound like a lot of work, which is something I am trying to save by doing it in the first place. I am going to delve into the code of this project to see how they solved it: https://github.com/holman/live-validations

Answer (score 10):

In Rails 3 you can call the `_validators` method on an object to get the list of validators that will run:

```
t = Ticket.new
t._validators
```

Comment: That sounds perfect if I was using rails 3, but I am on rails 2.3. So no go :-(

Comment: Good on rails 4 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know if this is a 'good' way, but you can initialize a new object, call #valid? on it and then call #errors to get a hash of attributes and error messages. Then you'd have to parse those errors messages.

```
user = User.new
user.valid?
errors_hash = user.errors
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. I have played with this, but this doesn't seem to help when it comes to getting a max length for a field. This is probably because the field is empty and therefore the max length validation does not fail, resulting in no errors appearing in the error hash. I want this to be a generic thing, so I don't want to have to make the max length validation fail on fields so I can access the errors.